# Como recoger un valor de un input procedente de funcion onchange para calculo de edad

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy con la duda/desconocimiento de utilizar los valores cargados a partir de un select con la funcion onchange que le otorga el valor.
En este caso es una fecha que se recoge en un input (fechanac_tr) y a posteriori me gustaria utilizar esta fecha para calcular la edad.

os paso codigo por si podeis ver como poder recoger la variable, ya que como lo introduzco me da error.

Probablemente es que no se como recoger el valor de js ya que ando muy pez con este lenguaje.

```
                        <label for="nombre" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Nombre:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select name="trabajador_ace" id="trabajador_ace" class="form-control" onchange="selectIdtr(event)">
                                <option value="0">--Seleccione trabajador--</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($trabajadores as $trabajador) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $trabajador['id_trabajador']; ?>" nombre_tr="<?php echo $trabajador['nombre_tr']; ?>" fechanac_tr="<?php echo $trabajador['fechanac_tr']; ?>"
                                        <?php echo $trabajador['nombre_tr']; ?> </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <script>
                    function selectIdtr(e) {
                        var nombre_tr = e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("nombre_tr")
                        document.getElementById("nombre_tr").value = nombre_tr
                        var fechanac_tr = e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("fechanac_tr")
                        document.getElementById("fechanac_tr").value = fechanac_tr
                                            }
                </script>


<div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="nombre_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Nombre</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" id="nombre_tr" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="fechanac_tr" class="col-form-label col-sm-4">Fecha Nac.</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="text" id="fechanac_tr" class="form-control" disabled>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                             <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                             
                                    <?php
                                    $cumpleanos = new DateTime('fechanac_tr');
                                    $hoy = new DateTime();
                                    $annos = $hoy->diff($cumpleanos);
                                    ?>
                                    <label for="edad" class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Edad</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                                        <input type="text" id="edad" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $annos->y; ?>" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
```

Comment: No se entiende el problema, ni el código. Debes agregar un [MCVE] que sea reproducible, ordenado y mínimo

Answer (score 0):

lo que te falta es utilizar, dentro de tu misma funcion del onchange
document.getElementById("elemnto donde quieres que se vea el resultado").value = "el nombre de tu variable que le quieres asignar"

con esto según la opción que tengas en el ComboBox, puedes asignar a otro input que el valor de una variable.

Comment: he probado de poner segun me comentas lo siguiente:
  var fechanac_tr = e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("fechanac_tr")
                        document.getElementById("fechanac_tr").value = fechanac_tr
                        document.getElementById("fechanac_tr").value = edad_tr

y me da el siguiente error: Fatal error
: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (edad_tr) at position 0 (e): The timezone could not be found in the database in

Comment: importante es que si traes variables con php, utilices el símbolo "$" para definirlas, y si son fechas con las funciones de php "date" y "strtotime" para darles formatos, por ultimo las puedes asignar de la siguiente forma:

        document.getElementById("nombre del elemento").value = $variable_PHP;